# Twillio Voice calling Angular2/Ionic2 Typescript

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic3, twilio

I am using cordova plugin https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio-voice-phonegap-plugin for implementing Twillio voice calling functionality in my app for both (iOS+Android).

I have also imported Twillio CDN in my Angular2/Ionic2 project by using:

CDN : `<script type="text/javascript" src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js"></script>`

and by declaring constant in my .ts file I can import twillio library

> declare const Twilio: any;

but how can I use/import TwilioVoiceClient for making voice calls in Angular2/Ionic2 - Typescript.

I want to use and make a voice call using -->

> Twilio.TwilioVoiceClient.call(token, params);

**Twilio.TwilioVoiceClient is throwing undefined.**